# Jquery Validation messages as a placeholder not clearing as you type

Tags: jquery, forms, jquery-validate, placeholder

I've got this mobile form which I am using jQuery Validation and so far I have managed to made it work with the .error element as a placeholder, the problem is that it keeps giving error messages within the placement and therefor does not want to add the .valid class if I type it actually does work with the Email and Password fields!

[Here is the fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/RicardoAlves/uemfoaoy/13/)

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#ValidateOrderRegistration").validate({

            rules: {
                FirstName: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 1
                },
                LastName: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 1
                },
                Username: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 2
                },
                Password: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 6
                },
                PasswordConfirm: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 6,
                    equalTo: "#f-password"
                },
                EmailAddress: {
                    required: true,
                    email: true
                },
            },

            messages: {   
                FirstName: {
                    required: "Please enter your First Name",
                    minlength: "Please enter at least 2 characters",
                },
                LastName: {
                    required: "Please enter your surname",
                    minlength: "Please enter at least 2 characters",
                },
                Password: {
                    required: "Enter a 6 or more digits password",
                    minlength: "At least 6 characters"
                },
                PasswordConfirm: {
                    required: "Confirm Password Password",
                    minlength: "Your password must be at least 6 characters"
                },
                EmailAddress: {
                    required: "Enter an Email",
                    email: "Not Valid"
                },
            },

            errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
                element.val(error[0].outerText);     
            }, //Puts errors as placeholders

        }) //add rules
    $(this).find("input[type=text]").each(function() {
            if ($(this).attr("placeholder") == $(this).val())
                $(this).val("");
        }) //validate everything
    $('.cat_textbox').on('click focusin', function() {
        this.value = '';
    }); //cleans fields
    $('#EmailAddress').on('click', function() {
        $('#EmailAddress .error').removeClass('error');
        $(this).addClass('success');
    }); //I tried this!
    $("#EmailAddress").click(function(e) {
        var email = $("#EmailAddress");
        var emailaddressVal = $("#EmailAddress").val();
        var emailReg = /^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@([A-Z0-9-]+\.)+[A-Z]{2,4}$/i;


        if (!emailReg.test(email.val())) {
            email.addClass("error").focus();

        } else {

            email.removeClass("error");
        } //
        return false;
    });
}); //MAIN VALIDATION
```

Comment: Why do you have two handlers for `#EmailAddress`? Why are you even manually validating while using validation plugin..? Why is this question tagged with ajax..?

Comment: *"if I type it actually does work with the Email and Password fields*" - it is not at all allowing me to enter anything in the email field... is that what you want..?

Comment: The second handler is something I tried to remove the class .error when you click on the email, if you have a look at the Fiddle you can see that when the placeholder error appears on the email it keeps saying not valid even if I just started to type but it doesn't clear!

Comment: You don't need a seperate handler to do that... you can add the code in existing handler. So what exactly is the issue, what do you want to happen in the fiddle..?

Comment: It should behave the same as the name and last name field, you click it clears the placeholder, you type and it's valid. But email and pass are giving me some trouble

Comment: I tried removing it but still doesn't work

Comment: Using the validation error as the placeholder... this is a terrible idea as far as GUI design is concerned. No user is expecting to see a validation message inside of the text field.  Not to mention that validation is triggered on every keystroke so you're not going to see a placeholder (validation message) while the user is actively typing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are currently setting the error message as the actual value of the element. Setting it as the `placeholder` will remove it once you click the element, and the plugin automatically removes the error class when validation succeeds.

Change `errorPlacement` to:

```
errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
    element.attr("placeholder", error[0].outerText);
}
```